# React Native - Parsing into exported file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

```
export const feeds = [
fetch('http://mydomain.de/api.php')
];
```

The api.php simply returns this:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Mehr als 32 cent ...","content":"inhalt"}]
```

What changes would need to be made so it just imports the content of api.php? The react-native documentation onfortunately doens't have an example for this.

Comment: There's no document as there's no need to fetch the API file contents ever. There's something definitely wrong that you are doing.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I need to fetch the files content as there's the json included in it.

Comment: API should return the JSON instead of getting the API file. Read more about it.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal The .php file on the server contains a json struct and then just echo's it with json_decode. Simple as that, i just need the content.

Comment: Kindly edit the question accordingly so that I can remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` returns a Promise, so you can not simply assign it to variable and expect immediate results.

You may want to do something like:

```
export const feeds = fetch('http://mydomain.de/api.php');
```

And then:

```
import {feeds} from 'MODULE ABOVE'
feeds.then(response => {
  // You array should be here (in the `response` variable)...
})
```

I hope I undertoood your intensions correctly :)

Comment: [This would be my attempt to show the data](https://hastebin.com/opusayuyoh.xml) That end's up in an error though.

Comment: I would suggest not to render data right away.
1. You may want to reuse it elsewhere or
2. You may want to show sort of 'loading...' text meantime while data is being loaded. So... you can get your response into the variable first, and then use variable to render you list.

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with that code anyway. React Native just throws out some gibberish error code. (Unexpected token, expected ,)

Comment: You may want to check the syntax. You may have a comma(s) after the methods in class or it can be related to the render function... May be you want to share more of your code so it's easier to get the clue.

Comment: That would be to long for a comment; Have a [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/unujicixes.scala)